# Type-safe way to transform a key and a value into an object with that single key/value

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function `valueToObject` that, given a key and a value, yields an object with that single key and value, e.g.:

```
valueToObject('myKey', 3);
// should return {myKey: 3}
```

I tried the following code:

```
type Wrapped<K extends string, V> = {
  [P in K]: V;
};
function valueToObject<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Wrapped<K, V> {
  return {[key]: value};
}
```

But this does not compile, unless I cast the return value to `any`:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to type 'Wrapped<K, V>'.
```

How can I write this function in a type-safe way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a computed property the type with a generic parameter the type will be inferred to `{ [name: string]: V }`. This seems to be related to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14473#issuecomment-287053561) issue, which although is marked as fixed, you can see @jcalz commented about 4 days ago that this is still happening on 2.9.

**Edit** [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) issue seems to be a close match and is still open with a target of 3.0 so we may get a fix soon

The only work around is to use a type assertion:

```
function valueToObject<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Wrapped<K, V> {
    return { [key]: value } as Wrapped<K, V>;
}
//OR
function valueToObject<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Wrapped<K, V> {
    var result = {} as   Wrapped<K, V>
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
}
```

I suggest you report this on GitHub, or comment on the issue to draw attention to the fact that this still happens.

Comment: Looks like [this still happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53068695).  No idea if the issue(s) in GitHub are going to be addressed.