# Typescript: object built with keyof object doesn't get recognized as such

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The following code has this error: `Type '{ [x: string]: IHasAgeAndName[K]; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<IHasAge, K>'.` What I don't understand is, since typescript enforces that propName is a key of `IHasAge`, why `pureHasAge` becomes `{ [x: string]: IHasAgeAndName[K]; }`? Doing this `const pureHasAge: Pick<IHasAge, K> = {...` also gives me the same error. In this scenario, propName can only be `'age'` and nothing else.

```
interface IHasAge {
    age: number;
}

interface IHasAgeAndName extends IHasAge{
    name: string;
}

const returnAge = <K extends keyof IHasAge>(hasAgeAndName: IHasAgeAndName, propName: K): Pick<IHasAge, K> => {
    const pureHasAge = {
        [propName]: hasAgeAndName[propName]
    };

    return pureHasAge;
};

returnAge({ age: 10, name: 'John' }, 'age');
```